# Surfaceview cannot be resolved

Tags: android, exception

I've been working on a project which uses `wowza media` engine to live stream on a website when video is taken through an `android phone`. But I'm unable to find the surfaceview as findviewbyId returns null.

**imports**

```
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
    import android.view.Window;
    import android.view.WindowManager;
    import java.util.regex.Matcher;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;
    import android.support.v7.appcompat.R;
    import edu.purdue.shishir.libs.Session;
    import edu.purdue.shishir.libs.SessionBuilder;     
    import edu.purdue.shishir.libs.audio.AudioQuality;
    import edu.purdue.shishir.libs.gl.SurfaceView;
    import edu.purdue.shishir.libs.rtsp.RtspClient;
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RtspClient.Callback,
        Session.Callback, SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    // log tag
    public final static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    // surfaceview
    private static SurfaceView mSurfaceView;

    // Rtsp session
    private Session mSession;
    private static RtspClient mClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        // getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);
        mSurfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(this);

        // Initialize RTSP client
        initRtspClient();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        //if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
          //  return true;
        //}

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void toggleStreaming() {
        if (!mClient.isStreaming()) {
            // Start camera preview
            mSession.startPreview();

            // Start video stream
            mClient.startStream();
        } else {
            // already streaming, stop streaming
            // stop camera preview
            mSession.stopPreview();

            // stop streaming
            mClient.stopStream();
        }
    }

    private void initRtspClient() {
        // Configures the SessionBuilder
        mSession = SessionBuilder.getInstance()
                .setContext(getApplicationContext())
                .setAudioEncoder(SessionBuilder.AUDIO_NONE)
                .setAudioQuality(new AudioQuality(8000, 16000))
                .setVideoEncoder(SessionBuilder.VIDEO_H264)
                .setSurfaceView(mSurfaceView).setPreviewOrientation(0)
                .setCallback(this).build();

        // Configures the RTSP client
        mClient = new RtspClient();
        mClient.setSession(mSession);
        mClient.setCallback(this);
        mSurfaceView.setAspectRatioMode(SurfaceView.ASPECT_RATIO_PREVIEW);
        String ip, port, path;

        // We parse the URI written in the Editext
        Pattern uri = Pattern.compile("rtsp://(.+):(\\d+)/(.+)");
        Matcher m = uri.matcher(AppConfig.STREAM_URL);
        m.find();
        ip = m.group(1);
        port = m.group(2);
        path = m.group(3);

        mClient.setCredentials(AppConfig.PUBLISHER_USERNAME,
                AppConfig.PUBLISHER_PASSWORD);
        mClient.setServerAddress(ip, Integer.parseInt(port));
        mClient.setStreamPath("/" + path);
    }

    private void alertError(final String msg) {
        final String error = (msg == null) ? "Unknown error: " : msg;
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setMessage(error).setPositiveButton("Ok",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        toggleStreaming();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        toggleStreaming();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mClient.release();
        mSession.release();
        mSurfaceView.getHolder().removeCallback(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSessionError(int reason, int streamType, Exception e) {
        switch (reason) {
            case Session.ERROR_CAMERA_ALREADY_IN_USE:
                break;
            case Session.ERROR_CAMERA_HAS_NO_FLASH:
                break;
            case Session.ERROR_INVALID_SURFACE:
                break;
            case Session.ERROR_STORAGE_NOT_READY:
                break;
            case Session.ERROR_CONFIGURATION_NOT_SUPPORTED:
                break;
            case Session.ERROR_OTHER:
                break;
        }

        if (e != null) {
            alertError(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRtspUpdate(int message, Exception exception) {
        switch (message) {
            case RtspClient.ERROR_CONNECTION_FAILED:
            case RtspClient.ERROR_WRONG_CREDENTIALS:
                alertError(exception.getMessage());
                exception.printStackTrace();
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onBitrareUpdate(long bitrate) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPreviewStarted() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSessionConfigured() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSessionStarted() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSessionStopped() {

    }
}
```

But R.id.surface cannot be resolved.

**Activity_main.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/surface_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded">

    <edu.purdue.shishir.libs.gl.SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surface"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot to load the `Activity_main.xml` layout in the `onCreate`.

Please, add following code in `onCreate`

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```